# Invertibility and inverse of a matrix sum with the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ an arbitrary $N \times N$-matrix and let $I$ be the $N \times N$-identity matrix.

1. Under what conditions on $B$ is $I + B$ invertible?
2. In cases of invertibility, how can then $(I + B)^{-1}$ be computed?

Comment: Hint: If $|x|<1$, $(1+x)^{-1}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1. The standard necessary and sufficient conditions are e.g. $\det(I + B) \neq 0$ or "$-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $B$". The present question seems to aim, however, at the (sufficient, but not necessary) condition that $\|B\| < 1$ in *some* [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).

Ad 2. Assume $\|B\| < 1$ in some matrix norm. Then the [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) can be used to write down and compute / approximate the inverse of $I + B$. A nice application of this is the "rendering equation" in computer graphics. If we do not have $\|B\| < 1$, the Neumann series need not converge.